# how to effectively use js.hidden

Tags: javascript

```
<table>
<tr><tr>
<tr id = select>custom dropdown select tag <tr>
<tr id = div1><tr>
<tr id = div2><tr>
<tr id = div3><tr>
<tr id = div4><tr>
<tr><tr>
<tr><tr>
</table>
```

I was looking for an efficient way to use js. hidden,
if getElementById(select) =1, only the tr tag with id 1 should be displayed, if getElementById(select) =3, id =div1,div2,div3 should be displayed and not 4. I'm currently writing an if else statement that goes something like this:

```
if(document.getelementbyid("select")value == 2){
   document.getelementbyid("div1").hidden = false ;
   document.getelementbyid("div2").hidden = false ;
   document.getelementbyid("div1").hidden = true;
   document.getelementbyid("div2").hidden = true;

}
else {
   document.getelementbyid("div1").hidden = false ;
   document.getelementbyid("div2").hidden = false ;
   document.getelementbyid("div1").hidden = false ;
   document.getelementbyid("div2").hidden = false ;
}
```

Similarly, I'm repeating for all values, but I'd like to know the most efficient way to do this, because I have many tr tags in the table with different ids that I want to change only with a specific 12 ids after select tag that has an id .

Comment: is code working as expected?

Comment: Use classes or other features to group the elements.

Comment: @ kritiz No this not my code but i wanted to explain it

Answer (score 0):

Use classes or other features to group the elements.

```js
const select = document.getElementById("select");
select.addEventListener('change', () => {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("group")).forEach(el => { el.hidden = true; });
  const value = +select.value;
  for (let i = 1; i <= value; ++i) {
    document.getElementById("div" + i).hidden = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
<tr><tr>
<tr><td><select id="select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4" selected>4</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="div1" class="group">A</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="div2" class="group">B</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="div3" class="group">C</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="div4" class="group">D</div></td></tr>
<tr><tr>
<tr><tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this looks nice

Comment: @jaba basically i have 12 tags which indicate 12 values of months , so if i select 1 then month 1 tr tag will be displayed , so all 12 tr tags must  have 12 different classes ?

Comment: @Srisai Your question description and code example is really bad. Yes, you need 12 IDs and one class.

Comment: <tr id="div12" class="group12">D<tr> should display all 12 tags

Comment: @Srisai Now, the select box selects the visible div.

Comment: @jabaa im very sorry as i have trouble explaining in English , if i select 2 then div 1,2 should display if 3 div 1,2,3 should display not 4 if div 4 then div 1,2,3,4 should display not  5

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mapping MAP to handle this situation is the best.

```js
const ValueMap = {
  1: {
    'div1': true
  }
}

elements.forEach(item => {
  item.hidden = !!ValueMap(value)[item.id]
})

// if Elements of many
const elements2 = docments.querySelectAll('tr[id^='div']')
elements2.forEach(item => {
  const id = item.id.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, "");
  if (+id <= value) {
    item.hidden = true
  } else {
    item.hidden = false
  };
})
```